# Initial submission action - should be locked - approval process

Tags: approval-process, automation, approval-step

object permission for the user:
[image]

I have the approval process and there is little tweak I need to do but I'm not sure if this is possible using the declarative, here is what I want to do.

When the record is submitted for initial approval I want the record to be locked and based on the screen shot it does looks like it locked but I was still able to update the record without the record is being approved and I tried with non admin user and I was able to change the record but I should not update the page since the page is locked correct?

[image]

Any help ?

Comment: does user have: `The “Modify All” object-level permission for the given object, or
The “Modify All Data” permission` ? see [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_create_recordeditability.htm&type=5)

Comment: I see the user has only `Read, Create, Edit, View All`

Comment: And the edit is being done via the standard UX?

Comment: that's correct from the UX page and I'm thinking maybe because I have field update?

Comment: No permission set that grants modify all?

Comment: thanks @cropredy it turns out that one of the PS has `Modify All`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SFDC Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_create_recordeditability.htm&type=5) states that editing locked records requires:

- `Modify All Data` (typically possessed by System Administrator profile users)
- `Modify All` for the SObjectType

Be sure to check the user's Profile and *all assigned Permission Sets* for this permission. A handy tool to do this is [Perm Comparator](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The below are the situations where user can able to edit the record during the approval process.

When a record is submitted for approval, it’s locked to prevent users from editing it during the approval process. Use the record editability properties to determine who can edit records that are locked in this approval process.

**Administrators ONLY can edit records during the approval process.**
Default. Lets users edit the record that’s pending approval only if they have:

The “Modify All” object-level permission for the given object, or
The “Modify All Data” permission

**Administrators OR the currently assigned approver can edit records during the approval process.**

by using this option, assigned users & admin can able to edit the record.

1. In your case check the respective user profile have “**Modify All Data**” permission.
2. Check the approval process who are all having the **Record Editability** Properties.
3. check the **final approval action** Record Lock type as "**Lock the record from being edited**" or not in the approval process.